# Google Analytics filter base on Event Value

Tags: google-analytics

Im using google analytics in my ios program to gets user Events.

this my code for capturing user interaction in my View :

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
     NSString* uniqueIdentifier = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor] UUIDString];
    id tracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] defaultTracker];

    [tracker set:@"&uid"
           value:uniqueIdentifier];

    [tracker send:[[GAIDictionaryBuilder createEventWithCategory:@"CategoryVisit"            
                                                          action:@"CategoryName"  
                                                           label:self.catname              
                                                           value:self.code] build]];
}
```

now how can i filter in admin panel base on event value ??
there is only filter base on "Action,Category,Label".

[image]

also is there possible way to filter base on uid ???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, event value is a metric, so you won't see it under the dimension tab. Second of all, &uid is a user ID and should have an associated custom dimension. It could be sent with the event hit which you would be able to show in the custom report.

Answer (score 1):

The event value is a metric so you won't view it in the dimensions tab.

Filter based on uid? The User ID? Nope that is not possible. However, you can do the following *hack*:

1. You create a custom dimension and set the uid there.
2. In your custom report you can then filter events based on that custom dimension.